# Origin of the phrase "under your belt"?

Tags: etymology, idioms

Today, I found myself discussing what students should have "under their belts" during a lecture, and I wondered to myself if there was some inappropriate undertone here that I might be unaware of.

> **Question**: What is the origin of the phrase "under your belt"?

A google search revealed some webpages (e.g. [[1]](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Where_did_the_expression_%27under_his_belt_come_from%27)) that assert its origin is related to consumption of food -- once a meal has been eaten, it's under your belt (which is a relief).  However, with such websites, I have no way to determine fact from "random guy on the internet making stuff up".

Comment: You must also consider that trouser waists used to be worn much higher than today. I don't think the expression has any sexual origins, though I have no evidence for that.

Comment: +1 for including the research you've done so far. (Plus, it's an interesting question)

Comment: Thanks for the great answers!!  (I picked one I liked as the "accepted" answer, but there was very little separating them.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Online Etymological Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=belt&allowed_in_frame=0) says:

> To get something *under (one's) belt* is to get it into one's stomach.

The Oxford English Dictionary says:

> Colloq. phr. ***under one's belt***, in one's stomach. Also *fig.*

Their first three citations are:

- 1839   *The Spirit of the Times*: Away we went, each bearing, under his belt, his full share of the antifogmatical?compound.
- 1938   *A Dictionary of American English on historical principles*: Belt, v.? To put under one's belt; to swallow.
- 1954   *The Manchester Guardian Weekly*:  His wife had 135,000 miles driving in the States under her belt?but was still failed.

Here's three earlier literal examples, all about a lot of alcohol under one's belt.

- [1762](http://books.google.fi/books?id=lTU0AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA60&dq=%22under%20*%20belt%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FR6-T9H_FabQ4QTfy-1N&redir_esc=y#v=thumbnail&q=%22under%20my%20belt%20%22&f=false)'s *The Young Hypocrite* by Samuel Foote:

[image: MAZURE. How can that be .' Can wine, that takes the ' senses away, restore them. again? COUNT. Pshaw ! you talk like a milkfop, Mr. Mayor f Why, I am never fo sensible, as when I am foaking ; with six bottles under my belt I am sit to]

- [1790](http://books.google.fi/books?id=zekNAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA64&dq=inauthor:%22Tobias%20George%20Smollett%22%20%22under%20his%20belt%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yBi-T7ekJ8HP4QSgpdVJ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22under%20his%20belt%22&f=false)'s *The Expedition of Humphry Clinker* by Tobias Smollett  (first published 1771):

[image: At half an hour past eight in the evening, he was carried home with six good bottles of claret under his belt; and it being then Friday. he gave orders that he should not be disturbed till Sunday at noon.]

- [1817](http://books.google.fi/books?id=jy4JAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA96&dq=inauthor:%22Maria%20Edgeworth%22%20%22under%20his%20belt%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lBe-T-jdNa344QTVsZEx&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22under%20his%20belt%20%22&f=false)'s *Ormond, a tale* by Maria Edgeworth:

[image: For his own part, it was his established rule never to go to bed without a proper quantity of liquor under his belt ; but he defied the universe to say he was ever known to be drunk.]

Answer (score 6):

The literal meaning of having something *under your belt* is having it in your stomach, but it’s probably more frequently used figuratively, to mean having acquired something, often intellectual. For example, the OED has these two supporting citations, from the English novelists P G Wodehouse (1954) and John Wain (1962):

> Just as you have got Hamlet and Macbeth under your belt
>
> He wanted me to get plenty of Latin and Greek under the belt so that I
>   could be like him.

*Below the belt* has a quite different meaning. It’s from the language of boxing, where the rules forbid hitting the lower abdomen. It, too, can be used figuratively to describe other kinds of unfair act.

Comment: I'd argue that even the _having it in your stomach_ is figurative as the first literal meaning of the phrase would have been to have something, like a weapon, hanging from one's belt.

Comment: @Callithumpian: The earliest "in your stomach" I found is [1762](http://books.google.fi/books?id=lTU0AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA60&dq=%22under%20%2a%20belt%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FR6-T9H_FabQ4QTfy-1N&redir_esc=y#v=thumbnail&q=%22under%20my%20belt%20%22&f=false), and "something hanging" from [1596](http://books.google.fi/books?id=C2QLAAAAIAAJ&pg=RA1-PA247&dq=%22under+*+belt%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XCi-T4i6G-bm4QStmt1u&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22under%20his%20belt%22&f=false) (and is that the first recorded emoticon in history roflol?! :)

Comment: In my opinion, a reference to a weapon under one's belt makes much more sense as the origin for experience/knowledge related meaning, than the idea of consumed food or drink. Past experience can be used as a "weapon", an instrument for future achievemnts. It's much more useful than a food or alcoholic dring, which actually makes you less apt if anything.

Answer (score 5):

The phrase seems to be of Scottish origin. As Hugo found, most of the earliest uses of the phrase have to do with alcohol consumption. I did find this earlier figurative use of the phrase however from *[The History Of The Church And State Of  Scotland](https://books.google.com/books?id=mQM-AAAAcAAJ&q=mdccliii#v=snippet&q=belt&f=false)*, 1753 ([date check](https://books.google.com/books?id=mQM-AAAAcAAJ&q=mdccliii#v=snippet&q=mdccliii&f=false)):

[image: https://books.google.com/books?id=mQM-AAAAcAAJ&q=mdccliii#v=snippet&q=belt&f=false]

It appears the figurative sense of *under one's belt* to mean owned or "contained by" goes back even further as evidenced by this old Scottish saying from *[A Complete Collection of Scotish Proverbs](https://books.google.com/books?id=BEgOAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA246&dq=%22under%20*%20belt%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DCO-T-udHPHgsQLR6vQb&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=%22under%20*%20belt%22&f=false)*, 1721:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps related to the 1721 Scottish saying "my tongue is not under your belt" is the Scottish proverb ["put thy thumb under my belt", to submit](http://books.google.fi/books?id=9x8EAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA219&dq=%22thy+thumb+under+my+belt%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AC2-T62BCMvY4QTdsc1W&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22thy%20thumb%20under%20my%20belt%22&f=false) (1848), listed in [1737](http://books.google.fi/books?id=MTRAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA307&dq=%22thy+thumb+under+*+belt%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-i2-T7mDKKmm4gSn7ZUX&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAA) as "thy thumb is under my belt".

Comment: Interesting. All these body parts under belts make me wonder if there's some more tangible origin out there. Then there's _under one's thumb_, _tread under foot_, etc.

Comment: A belt can be used for corporal punishment. Your quotes make me wonder if the phrase originally meant under your control (through violent coercion).

Comment: Look, the meaning seems pretty clear here: If it's under your belt, it's *part of you*, yes? You've, at least figuratively, eaten it. If the food & drink are *over* your belt, they could be on the table; anyone could take them in. If they're *under* your belt, they are, as [Mike Myers colorfully (?) tells us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Bastard#Popular_culture_and_DirecTV_commercial), **in our belly** and under our control. It seems the meaning could be exceptionally straightforward from this context.

Answer (score 3):

Under your belt means --

**"to have learned or succeeded in something which might be an advantage in the future."**

e.g. Basic computer skills are a good thing to have **under your belt**.

Comment: Can you cite your source?

Comment: ya. i got it from the Cambridge advanced dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

There’s also the use in boxing. Under the belt means something like a low blow. In boxing it’s illegal to punch under the belt for obvious reasons, so the phrase that's “under the belt” can mean foul play. To have something under YOUR belt is about acquiring.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).